# Retrieve the date portion of date object in milliseconds

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, angular-ui-bootstrap, milliseconds

How can I get the date portion of a `Date` object in milliseconds in javascript?

I didn't find [any method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to this. I was trying:

```
var today = new Date();
var datePortion = today.toDateString();
var inMiliseconds = new Date(datePortion).getMilliseconds();
console.log(inMiliseconds);
```

The return is always `0`. See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/james_dbrown/83kbuupt/).

What can I do?

**Backgroud**:

What I want is get the date and time portions in two separated fields and then add the two values (in milliseconds) to get new date. 
I'm getting the two dates using the [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)'s datepicker and timepicker in the HTML below

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="InitialDate">Date:</label>
    <div id="InitialDate" class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="Initial" data-datepicker-popup="yyyy/MM/dd" data-ng-model="date"
               data-is-open="datepickers.date" data-datepicker-options="dateOptions" data-date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" data-ng-required="true"/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="open($event)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <timepicker data-ng-model="hour" data-ng-change="changed()" data-hour-step="1" data-minute-step="5" data-show-meridian="ismeridian"></timepicker>
</div>
```

I'm recovering the two values in my controller, but they are sent as `Date` objects, so I need to get the date portion of the date field and the time portion of the time field in milliseconds.

Any tip or advice are welcome.

Comment: Why don't you just do `today.getMilliseconds();`

Comment: The problem is `toDateString` returns a regular string, not a date object with a set milliseconds. You probably want to capture the milliseconds when you capture the date.

Comment: @jackyrudetsky Correct me if I'm wrong, but `today.getMilliseconds()` will return the value in milliseconds of the date and time. I want the value of the date portion. For example in the object `Wed Jun 17 2015 14:22:56 GMT-0300` I want the value in milliseconds of the `Wed Jun 17 2015 00:00:00`, ignoring the time portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getMilliseconds()` returns the milliseconds part of the date, which is `0` is your case, since you constructed it from the date part (only) of a date.

If I understand the requirement correctly, you're trying to get the date's representation as the number of milliseconds from the epoc. This is done by the `getTime()` method (I concede it's a less-than-brilliant name for that method). So, long story short:

```
var today = new Date();
var datePortion = today.toDateString();
var inMiliseconds = new Date(datePortion).getTime();
console.log(inMiliseconds);
```